# Alternative to value_or that is indifferent to the returned type

Tags: c++, stdoptional

I have built a little class `Card` overloading the `<<` operator, essentially printing out Suit and value of the card.

The implementation details are not relevant for the question I want to ask here just assume the obvious. For `Card` I built a class `CardDeck`. Of course a `CardDeck` can run out of cards. That motivated me to this attempt:

```
std::optional<Card> CardDeck::drawCard() {
    if (this->Cards.empty()) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    else {
        Card card = this->Cards.front();
        this->Cards.pop_front();
        return std::optional<Card>{card};
    }
}
```

Now one can draw a card and dealing with the possibility of a empty deck is the responsibility of client code using `CardDeck`, yet it is verbose that the method will not always return a value. I like that solution.

Anyways a newbie to C++ I made the naive ansatz:

`std::cout<< cardDeck.drawCard().value_or("Out of cards!");`

This fails as the type of `"Out of cards!"` is `char*` but not `Card`.

My question: Is there a way to safe the elegant oneliner without checking and accessing the vaule / using the replacement in two seperate places?

Comment: How about overloading `operator<<` with `std::optional<Card>`?

Comment: Perhaps provide a free function `std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::optional<Card>&)`.

Comment: Something like `my_optional_visit(cardDeck.drawCard(), [](const Card&c){ std::cout << c; }, [](){ std::cout << "Out of Cards!" });`.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this in my opion is to add an overload for `operator <<` for `std::optional<Card>`.  In there you can handle the logic on what to print like

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const std::optional<Card>& card)
{
    if (card == std::nullopt)
        return os << "Out of cards!";
    else
        return os << *card;
}
```

and then you can just have

```
std::cout << cardDeck.drawCard();
```

Comment: The only concern I would voice is the loss of flexibility. In more modern languages the string could be adapted to the respective situation. e.g. `std::cout<<cardDeck.drawCard().value_or("Damn thief, give me my cards back!");`.

Comment: @ThomasEberhard I think that would be a valid addition to your question, that you want the text to be context dependent.

Comment: @ThomasEberhard Yes, you do lose some flexibiltiy. If you want that functionality then I would suggest Jarod42's answer or something like Parker Coates answer.

Answer (score 4):

You might write generic helper function a la `std::visit` for variant but for `std::optional`, something like:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename FEmpty>
auto my_optional_visit(const std::optional<T>& o, F f, FEmpty fEmpty)
{
    return o ? f(*o) : fEmpty();
}
```

and then:

```
my_optional_visit(cardDeck.drawCard(),
                  [](const Card&c){ std::cout << c; },
                  [](){ std::cout << "Out of Cards!" });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function (either namespace scoped or a static member of card) that takes a `std::optional<Card>` and return its textual representaion as a string. The relevant bits would be:

```
class Card {
    ...
    std::string repr() const {
        std::string cr;
        // writes the textual representation of a card here
        return cr;
    }
    static std::string repr(const std::optional<Card> &card) {
        if (card.has_value()) {
            return card.value().repr();
        }
        return "Out of cards!";
    }
};

std::ostream& operator << (std ostream& out, const Card& card) {
    out << card.repr();
}
```

You would then simply use:

```
std::cout << Card::repr(cardDeck.drawCard());
```

Answer (score 0):

A C++ function can only have one return type. In your case you'd like the type of the result to be determined at runtime, where it could be different every time it's called. That just isn't possible.

If you need to do this often enough, I'd suggest just creating a small wrapper function.

```
std::string optionalCardToString(const std::optional<Card> & card,
                                 const std::string & emptyString) {
    return card ? card->to_string() : emptyString;
}

std::cout << optionalCardToString(cardDeck.drawCard(), "Out of Cards");
```

If performance is a concern, there's plenty you could do to make this more efficient to avoid making copies, but the general idea is there.

I should note that in a real world scenario, you are unlikely to draw a `Card` from the `CarDeck` and just pipe it to `cout`. You typically will want to do something else with the card as well, such as add it to a `Hand` or a `Pile`. This need to do something else sort of negates your concern about having to mention the value more than once.